# Is there any reason to use `default: nil` in a Rails migration for Postgres?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, migration

I see `default: nil` in the migration file of a Rails project I'm working on. In Postgres this results in a `NULL` value in the db.

Is there any reason why someone would use this?

It seems to me, the same result can be achieved by just skipping setting a default, and the value will be `NULL` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I'm asking myself the same question right now. I have two columns on a model that should always be 'nil' to reflect a legacy system decision.

...

I don't think there is a reason to do this, as you say, it defaults to nil. In my case, I've decided to use `validates_absence_of :field` aswell.

It may not exactly be an answer but someone might find comfort that someone else is doing it like this. I'd be keen to know the disadvantages of implicitly assuming the field will just always stay `nil`.

Answer (score -1):

Validations can be Skipped unlike database constraints

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).